# Skype is not working after installing lxqt on ubuntu 19.10

Tags: lubuntu, skype, lxqt

I had this huge issue with my ram ussage so I decided to install lxqt.
After switching to lxqt desktop my skype and some other applications were not working fine so I decided to uninstall lubuntu-desktop and lxqt and switch back to ubuntu 19's own desktop.

But My skype was removed from the taskbar and also when I attempt to open it, it just doesn't open ( it opens a terminal window then suddenly closes that window and nothing else happens). I tried removing it and installing it again from Ubuntu software center and also via Snap but it just doesnt open anymore. What should I do? I really need it.

Comment: Please clarify you release. There is no Ubuntu 19, as server & desktop releases use the *yy.mm* format, and no Ubuntu Core 19 (IoT or specialist *snap* based releases do use *yy* format but are used without desktop usually).

Comment: ok im gonna edit my question.

Comment: Try running skype from terminal. If you have the.deb version run `skype` and if you have the snap run `snap run skype`. Notice any errors? If you do, then edit your question adding them. You may have removed other important packages by mistake when you removed lubuntu-desktop. Try installing `ubuntu-desktop` again with `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop` and reboot.